# What is spb_raw_html in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to edit a page in WP (not the original owner, so I don't know how it was configured) and the post contents (visual + text) shows:

```
[spb_raw_html width="1/2" el_position="first"]OEKF93JIFO4F...
```

Etc. A hundred+ lines of letters and numbers. First, I'm just trying to identify what this is so I can edit the page.

Answer (score 0):

It is a page build with Swift Page Builder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).